# What is wrong with this program calling a function pointer with a parameter pack?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

According to my understanding, the following program should obviously print:

```
1.0 hello world 42
```

However, it fails to compile. Why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template<class... InitialArgTypes>
void CallWithExtraParameter(void (*funcPtr)(InitialArgTypes..., int), InitialArgTypes... initialArgs)
{
    (*funcPtr)(initialArgs..., 42);
}

void Callee(double a, string b, int c)
{
    cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << endl;
}

int main()
{
    CallWithExtraParameter<double, string>(Callee, 1.0, string("hello world"));
}
```

[Compiler output:](http://ideone.com/fdACkz)

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:18:75: error: no matching function for call to 'CallWithExtraParameter(void (&)(double, std::string, int), double, std::string)'
  CallWithExtraParameter<double, string>(Callee, 1.0, string("hello world"));
                                                                           ^
prog.cpp:6:6: note: candidate: template<class ... InitialArgTypes> void CallWithExtraParameter(void (*)(InitialArgTypes ..., int), InitialArgTypes ...)
 void CallWithExtraParameter(void (*funcPtr)(InitialArgTypes..., int), InitialArgTypes... initialArgs)
      ^
prog.cpp:6:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cpp:18:75: note:   mismatched types 'int' and 'double'
  CallWithExtraParameter<double, string>(Callee, 1.0, string("hello world"));
                                                                           ^
```

Comment: did you try putting double instead of int?

Comment: At least, it should be `CallWithExtraParameter<double, string>(Callee, 1.0, string{"hello world"});`. Shouldn't it?

Comment: @skypjack Probably. (My actual code isn't passing a string here, I just picked some random types for the MCVE)

Comment: Curiously, separating the argument deductions still fails: http://ideone.com/50KlFg

Answer (score 5):

First, `"hello world"` wouldn't deduce to `std::string`, it would deduce to `const char*`, which doesn't match `Callee`, so let's fix your call to be pass `"hello world"s` instead.

Second, there appears to be some issue with having an argument of type:

```
void (*funcPtr)(InitialArgTypes..., int)
```

That is apparently in some limbo between non-deduced context and deducible - in that it's not a non-deduced context (otherwise `InitialArgTypes...` would've been deduced from the other parameters) and it's not deducible (because it still failed). So let's go one step further and definitively make it a non-deduced context:

```
template <class T> struct identity { using type = T; };
template <class T> using identity_t = typename identity<T>::type;

template <class... InitialArgTypes>
void CallWithExtraParameter(void (*funcPtr)(identity_t<InitialArgTypes>..., int),
        InitialArgTypes... initialArgs)
{
    (*funcPtr)(initialArgs..., 42);
}
```

*Now*, `InitialArgTypes...` will be deduced from the arguments passed in at the end. Which is what we want, so this works:

```
CallWithExtraParameter(Callee, 1.0, "hello world"s);
```

Comment: Isn't the string deduced as `const char [N]`?

Comment: Didn't I explicitly specify the template parameters as `<double, string>`?

Comment: @skypjack No, the args are deduced by value, not by reference.

Comment: @Barry Well, GCC was saying that `std::string` and `const char[12]` where not the same type in the first example posted by the OP, so...

Comment: @T.C. The resolution there says that it will never be deduced. But it even fails when OP explicitly provides the types (unlike the example given with `g`)

Comment: Ugh. Yeah, I've seen this exact scenario multiple times on SO, and I can never make any sense out of the standard text :/

Comment: @T.C. We'll if you cant, what hope have I? :) I'm sticking with my purgatory theory. I feel like it just generally sums up templates.

Comment: Making things extra fun: `template<class... T> void CallWithExtraParameter(void (*funcPtr)(T..., int, T...), T... t);` (with suitable changes elsewhere) works with Clang with or without explicitly specified template arguments, but not GCC.

Comment: ...and then Clang does something *really* weird: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc60c55cb4da9140 I'm going to go with buggy compilers all around plus clear-as-mud standardese. A wonderful combination, to be sure.

Comment: @T.C. At least that OK (in a vacuum) I understand. But why that line is OK and the others error? Sounds like a new CWG issue...

Comment: Sorry, but I can't accept this answer because the template parameters are explicitly specified and shouldn't need to be deduced.

Answer (score 2):

The *why* has been explained in another answer.
Anyway, I'd like to post that one to suggest one more solution.
It follows a working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<class... C>
struct Fn {
    using type = void (*)(C..., int);
};

template<class... InitialArgTypes>
void CallWithExtraParameter(typename Fn<InitialArgTypes...>::type funcPtr, InitialArgTypes... initialArgs)
{
    (*funcPtr)(initialArgs..., 42);
}

void Callee(double a, string b, int c)
{
    cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << endl;
}

int main()
{
    CallWithExtraParameter<double, string>(Callee, 1.0, string("hello world"));
}
```

Comment: Not sure why somebody downvoted this; this actually isn't bad.

Comment: @T.C. Actually I don't know, it's quite annoying to see that people downvotes valid responses without a comment. Anyway, your *isn't bad* is more than an upvote for me!! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generalization to any size tail that might be of use to you.  It is also more generic regarding the callable type (e.g. member function pointer is tested here too).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

template <typename Callable> struct Invoke;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct Invoke<R(*)(Args...)> {
    template <typename F, typename Tuple, std::size_t... Is, typename... As>
    static R execute (F funcPtr, Tuple&& tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>, As&&... as) {
        return (*funcPtr)(std::forward<As>(as)..., std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))...); 
    }
};

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct Invoke<R(C::*)(Args...)> {
    template <typename F, typename Tuple, std::size_t... Is, typename... As>
    static R execute (F f, Tuple&& tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>, C& c, As&&... as) {
        return (c.*f)(std::forward<As>(as)..., std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))...); 
    }
    template <typename F, typename Tuple, std::size_t... Is, typename... As>
    static R execute (F f, Tuple&& tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>, C* c, As&&... as) {
        return (c->*f)(std::forward<As>(as)..., std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))...); 
    }
};

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct Invoke<R(C::*)(Args...) const> {
    template <typename F, typename Tuple, std::size_t... Is, typename... As>
    static R execute (F f, Tuple&& tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>, C& c, As&&... as) {
        return (c.*f)(std::forward<As>(as)..., std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))...); 
    }
    template <typename F, typename Tuple, std::size_t... Is, typename... As>
    static R execute (F f, Tuple&& tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>, const C* c, As&&... as) {
        return (c->*f)(std::forward<As>(as)..., std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))...); 
    }
};

template <typename Functor>
struct Invoke : Invoke<decltype(&Functor::operator())> {};
// etc...

template <typename R = void, typename F, typename Tuple, typename... Args>
R invokeWithTupleTail (F funcPtr, Tuple&& tuple, Args&&... args) {
    return Invoke<F>::execute(funcPtr, std::forward<Tuple>(tuple),
        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value>{}, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

// Testing
struct Thing {
    int call (char k, int n, double a, std::string b, int c) {
        std::cout << k << ' ' << n << ' ' << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << '\n';
        return 5;
    }
    int doIt (char k, int n, double a, std::string b, int c) const {
        std::cout << k << ' ' << n << ' ' << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << '\n';
        return 12;
    }
    int operator() (char k, int n, double a, std::string b, int c) const {
        std::cout << k << ' ' << n << ' ' << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << '\n';
        return 20;
    }
};

void foo (char k, int n, double a, std::string b, int c) {
    std::cout << k << ' ' << n << ' ' << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << '\n';
}

int bar (char k, int n, double a, std::string b, int c) {
    std::cout << k << ' ' << n << ' ' << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << '\n';
    return 10;
}

int main() {
    const auto tupleTail = std::make_tuple(1.5, std::string("hello"), 42);
    invokeWithTupleTail(foo, tupleTail, 'a', 8);  // a 8 1.5 hello world 42
    int a = invokeWithTupleTail<int>(&bar, tupleTail, 'a', 8);  // a 8 1.5 hello world 42
    std::cout << a << '\n';  // 10

    Thing thing;
    a = invokeWithTupleTail<int>(&Thing::call, tupleTail, thing, 'a', 8);  // a 8 1.5 hello world 42
    std::cout << a << '\n';  // 5
    a = invokeWithTupleTail<int>(&Thing::doIt, tupleTail, &thing, 'a', 8);  // a 8 1.5 hello world 42
    std::cout << a << '\n';  // 12
    a = invokeWithTupleTail<int>(&Thing::operator(), tupleTail, thing, 'a', 8);  // a 8 1.5 hello world 42
    std::cout << a << '\n';  // 20
}
```